# App Delete Lock - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a app that blocks certain websites. I was wondering if there was any way to create a "Delete Lock" (where the user has to enter a passcode set previously in order to delete the app)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are getting there, mind to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot control the users over deleting your app with passcode. Apple does not provide those restrictions for the developers.

May be you can do it if your device is Jailbroken.

You can go upto having a passcode inside your app to use the app.

Comment: I want to have a passcode lock so that children can't delete the website blocker. Is there a way to hide it or another option?

Comment: i thought your question was a bit programmatic. But anyways you can do it by using restrictions in settings. http://www.ianswerguy.com/prevent-apps-from-being-deleted/